# TimeoutError: Worker failed to start

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, tornado, dask, dask-distributed

I work in an environment conda on jupyter notebook.
When trying to create a client using processes as follows

```
from dask.distributed import Client, progress

client = Client(processes = True)
```

**the following error occurs**

> ```
>  TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in
> ```
>
> callback(f)
>               827                 try:
>           --> 828                     result_list.append(f.result())
>               829                 except Exception as e:
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py
> ```
>
> in result(self, timeout)
>               237             try:
>           --> 238                 raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>               239             finally:
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/util.py in
> ```
>
> raise_exc_info(exc_info)
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in
> ```
>
> run(self)
>              1068                     else:
>           -> 1069                         yielded = self.gen.send(value)
>              1070
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py
> ```
>
> in _start_worker(self, death_timeout, **kwargs)
>               228             self.workers.remove(w)
>           --> 229             raise gen.TimeoutError("Worker failed to start")
>               230
>
> ```
>     TimeoutError: Worker failed to start
>
>     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>     TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
>     <ipython-input-26-9ebe205475b6> in <module>()
>           3 
>           4 # Use all 8 cores
>     ----> 5 cluster = LocalCluster(processes = True, n_workers = 4)
>           6 ##client = Client(processes = True)
>           7 ##client = Client('localhost:8789')
>
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py
> ```
>
> in **init**(self, n_workers, threads_per_worker, processes, loop,
>   start, ip, scheduler_port, silence_logs, diagnostics_port, services,
>   worker_services, service_kwargs, asynchronous, security,
>   **worker_kwargs)
>               140             self.worker_kwargs['security'] = security
>               141 
>           --> 142         self.start(ip=ip, n_workers=n_workers)
>               143 
>               144         clusters_to_close.add(self)
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py
> ```
>
> in start(self, **kwargs)
>               177             self._started = self._start(**kwargs)
>               178         else:
>           --> 179             self.sync(self._start, **kwargs)
>               180 
>               181     @gen.coroutine
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py
> ```
>
> in sync(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
>               170             return future
>               171         else:
>           --> 172             return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
>               173 
>               174     def start(self, **kwargs):
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py
> ```
>
> in sync(loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
>               275             e.wait(10)
>               276     if error[0]:
>           --> 277         six.reraise(*error[0])
>               278     else:
>               279         return result[0]
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
>         691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
>         692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>     --> 693             raise value
>         694         finally:
>         695             value = None
>
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py
> ```
>
> in f()
>               260             if timeout is not None:
>               261                 future = gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=timeout), future)
>           --> 262             result[0] = yield future
>               263         except Exception as exc:
>               264             error[0] = sys.exc_info()
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in
> ```
>
> run(self)
>              1053 
>              1054                     try:
>           -> 1055                         value = future.result()
>              1056                     except Exception:
>              1057                         self.had_exception = True
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py
> ```
>
> in result(self, timeout)
>               236         if self._exc_info is not None:
>               237             try:
>           --> 238                 raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>               239             finally:
>               240                 self = None
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/util.py in
> ```
>
> raise_exc_info(exc_info)
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in
> ```
>
> run(self)
>              1061                     if exc_info is not None:
>              1062                         try:
>           -> 1063                             yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
>              1064                         finally:
>              1065                             # Break up a reference to itself
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py
> ```
>
> in _start(self, ip, n_workers)
>               197         self.scheduler.start(scheduler_address)
>               198 
>           --> 199         yield [self._start_worker(**self.worker_kwargs) for i in range(n_workers)]
>               200 
>               201         self.status = 'running'
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in
> ```
>
> run(self)
>              1053 
>              1054                     try:
>           -> 1055                         value = future.result()
>              1056                     except Exception:
>              1057                         self.had_exception = True
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py
> ```
>
> in result(self, timeout)
>               236         if self._exc_info is not None:
>               237             try:
>           --> 238                 raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>               239             finally:
>               240                 self = None
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/util.py in
> ```
>
> raise_exc_info(exc_info)
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in
> ```
>
> callback(f)
>               826             for f in children:
>               827                 try:
>           --> 828                     result_list.append(f.result())
>               829                 except Exception as e:
>               830                     if future.done():
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py
> ```
>
> in result(self, timeout)
>               236         if self._exc_info is not None:
>               237             try:
>           --> 238                 raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
>               239             finally:
>               240                 self = None
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/util.py in
> ```
>
> raise_exc_info(exc_info)
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in
> ```
>
> run(self)
>              1067                             exc_info = None
>              1068                     else:
>           -> 1069                         yielded = self.gen.send(value)
>              1070 
>              1071                     if stack_context._state.contexts is not orig_stack_contexts:
>
> ```
>     /home/vlad/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/deploy/local.py
> ```
>
> in _start_worker(self, death_timeout, **kwargs)
>               227         if w.status == 'closed' and self.scheduler.status == 'running':
>               228             self.workers.remove(w)
>           --> 229             raise gen.TimeoutError("Worker failed to start")
>               230 
>               231         raise gen.Return(w)
>
> ```
>     TimeoutError: Worker failed to start
> ```

How can I solve this problem? I have the following setup
python version:  **3.6.9** 
dask version **1.1.4** 
distributed version **1.26.0** 
tornado version **4.5** 
conda **4.6.14**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by updating packages dask,distributed,tornado to version respectively 2.4.0 , 2.4.0,  6.0.3